# This simple sample runs in jshell but not in jbang. What could cause this difference?

Tags: java, jshell, jbang

I'm trying to get a simple jbang with dependency on class path sample working.
When I run the exact same java file (except for bulleted differences below) via jshell under Java 17, passing the same class path, it succeeds.

- The function definition in the jshell version is `static void b() throws ClassNotFoundException`.
- After starting jshell, I invoked it via `B.b()`

`jshell 'D:\path\B.java' --class-path "C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\Java\sajdbc4.jar"`

I added output of class path, my class path is present when running via jbang.  I'm passing the java version to eliminate that difference.

`jbang  --java 17 --cp 'C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\Java\sajdbc4.jar' D:\path\B.java`

Output follows.  "No suitable driver" indicates it can't load the dependent jar that's on the class path:

*C:\Users__.jbang\cache\jars\B.java.e22a3a302f133969cf194e974e813de59d453fcca7dc31fadde218d8503ab273\B.jar;"C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 17\Java\sajdbc4.jar"

Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlanywhere:HOST=127.0.0.1;UID=*****;PWD=__*

Here are the Java file contents:

```
///usr/bin/env jbang "$0" "$@" ; exit $?

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class B
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlanywhere:HOST=127.0.0.1;UID=*****;PWD=******");
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select 1") )
        {
            try  (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery())
            {
                if (rs.next()) 
                {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which version of jbang ?

I get this error indicating jdbc driver is being loaded: 

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path: /Users/manderse/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2429)
 at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)"

I'm wondering if the spaces in name causes issues? try put the jar local so you can do `--cp sajdbc4.jar`  to avoid any spacing?